# Need to work on an array recursively, trouble passing data, java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, recursion

Ok, I am having a really beginner mistake here, but I can't think of what I need to do. I have an array permArray that I am recursively filling with possible permutations. I have a public method that gets the parameters ready, then I work on the array in the private method that calls itself to work on smaller and smaller parts.

The problem I am having, is how do I pass the finished array back to the public method. Would I return the array every time I am finished with the recursion (after I have placed the last element in each section, where the section size is 1).

Oh, and also, this is practice, not homework.

```
//todo:
//need to determine what is wrong with my array of linked lists
package wordchains;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.xml.soap.Node;

/**
 *
 * @author Samuel French
 */
public class WordChains {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //variables
    int numWords = -1; //This will hold the number of words the user is inputting
    String userInput; //holds the user input to be broken up into a string array

    //Get the user's input, 0 is the quit value
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of words: ");
    numWords = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(">");
    sc.nextLine();
    userInput = sc.nextLine();
    String[] inputWords = userInput.split("\\s+");
    int numElements = inputWords.length;
    int numOfPerms = numOfPerms(numElements);

    //We will start by checking the last letter of the first word
    char cTest;
    int wordChecking = 0;

    int[][] permArray = genPerms(numElements, numOfPerms);

    for (int col = 0; col < numOfPerms; col++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int row = 0; row < numElements; row++) {
            System.out.print(permArray[col][row] + " ");
        }

    }

}

public static int numOfPerms(int numElements) {
    int numOfPerms = numElements;
    numElements--;
    while (numElements > 0) {
        numOfPerms = numOfPerms * numElements;
        System.out.println(numOfPerms);
        numElements--;
    }
    return numOfPerms;
}

public static int[][] genPerms(int numElements, int totPerms) {
    int permArray[][] = new int[totPerms][numElements];
    //either do it like this or create an array of head nodes
    List<LinkedList<Integer>> elementsLeftList = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
    LinkedList tempList = new LinkedList();
    for (int x = 0; x < numElements; x++) {
        tempList.addLast(x);
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < totPerms; x++) {
        elementsLeftList.add((LinkedList<Integer>) tempList.clone());
    }

    return privateGenPerms(permArray,elementsLeftList,totPerms,0,0,totPerms);
}

private static void privateGenPerms(int[][] permArray, List<LinkedList<Integer>> elementsLeftList, int totalPermutations, int elementPlacing, int sectionBegin, int sectionSize) {
    //variables-

//totalPermutations - the total number of permutations in the whole problem

//elementPlacing - the element currently being placed's position, corresponds to the rows of permArray
//elementPlacingIndex - the number of times the element currently being placed has been placed
//sectionSize - the size of the total working section. First time this is the # of permutations

//permCounter - this counter counts the permutation working with within the section
//sectionBegin - counts the beginning of the section working with


//2 Data structures:

//permArray - 2d the array of permutations
//elementsLeftList - list of lists of elements left, corresponds to each permutation


    int totalNumberOfElements = permArray[0].length;
    //
    int numberOfElementsLeftToPlace = totalNumberOfElements - elementPlacing;
    //

    int permCounter = sectionBegin;
    //Base case
    if (numberOfElementsLeftToPlace == 1) {
        for (int x = 0; x < totalPermutations; x++) {
            permArray[x][totalNumberOfElements - 1] = (int) elementsLeftList.get(permCounter).remove(0); //may need to be a remove 1, not sure
        }
        return; //need to decide what I am going to do here
    }

    //
    int elementPlacingIndex = 0;
    int elementCurrentlyPlacing = 0; //could be a 1, don't remember
    //
    int numberOfTimesToPlaceWithinCol = (sectionSize / numberOfElementsLeftToPlace);
    //
    //
    for (; permCounter < (sectionBegin + sectionSize); permCounter++) {
        //when we need to switch to a different partition of the section
        if (elementPlacingIndex == numberOfTimesToPlaceWithinCol) {
            elementPlacingIndex = 0;
            elementCurrentlyPlacing++;
        }
        permArray[permCounter][elementPlacing] = (int) elementsLeftList.get(permCounter).remove(elementCurrentlyPlacing);
        elementPlacingIndex++;
    }
    for (int newSectionBegin = sectionBegin; newSectionBegin < (sectionBegin + sectionSize); newSectionBegin = newSectionBegin + numberOfTimesToPlaceWithinCol) {
        privateGenPerms(permArray, elementsLeftList, totalPermutations, (elementPlacing + 1), newSectionBegin, (sectionSize / numberOfElementsLeftToPlace));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your expected input and your expected output in the form of examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is passed-by-reference, so any changes you make in the private function will be permanent and you do not need to return the modified array again.

I have not looked at your logic to see if this is the correct way to do it in your case though.